# Need to checkin 30 Common file when 2 developers working on Same Branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

We are two developers working on the same Project within the same Branch. Dev 'A' is doing small refactoring work which will impact 150 files and Dev 'B' is working on a subset of files which are around 30.
Dev 'B' has checked in the changes(30 files) and Dev'A' has pulled the latest changes from remote repo which includes Dev 'B' changes also but got below error message

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by merge: File1  file2 ........... File 50

Now the problem is Pull didn't happen successfully as got error message related to merging including impact on 50 files. 
What Dev'A' can do to push his changes to a remote location without affecting Dev'B' Changes?

Comment: Dev A shouldn't pull with uncommitted changes. Commit first, then pull. If you want both developers to be able to push in isolation you need at least 2 branches.

Comment: Dev A commit changes, pull the code. resolve merge conflicts if any, continue the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev A MUST:

1. merge the changes
2. do code review with peer (preferrably Dev A)
3. make sure the merged code compiles and run
4. run static analysis if normally used in your team
5. run regression tests / automatic tests
6. git push

Comment: merge was unsuccessful.I got below error
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

Comment: commit your changes (do not push), then pull and merge.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

Dev B should save their work in a private branch, get Dev A's changes, and then merge it all, using Git's help to resolve the conflicts.

**The problem**

Although Dev A's approach is going to create work for others, it's Dev B that needs to change how they fetch A's work to protect their own. This is a situation where you are pushing the limits of the automation that `git pull` provides.

`git pull` combines several operations:

- `git fetch` - fetch changes from the remote
- `git merge` - merge `origin/branch` into the local `branch`
- merge local changes into the results, applying your work to the results of the merge

The first two operations are safe, since the merge is fully reversible if you didn't like the results.

But the third operation has to touch your local changes, and could damage your working directory in some cases, which is what Git detected and warned Dev B about. Any merge conflict over the local changes should cause that message.

**Simplest solution: local commit**

Dev B can commit the changes to their local `branch` and rebase or merge with the remote one. I personally prefer the additional control a private branch gives me (see below), but this option takes fewer steps, so you might prefer it:

```
git commit -a -m'description'
git fetch
```

Examine the differences between `branch` and `origin/branch` and then choose either `git rebase origin/branch` or `git merge origin/branch` and resolve all conflicts using `git mergetool`.

**More control: create a private branch**

Dev B can also choose to commit their work into a private dev branch that can be rebased back onto `branch` later,

```
git checkout -b dev.protecting-my-work
git commit -a -m'work in progress'
```

And then go back to the shared `branch` and update it

```
git checkout branch
git fetch
# inspect what been fetched before merging:
git log --decorate --graph --format=oneline branch origin/branch
git merge # or maybe git rebase; that's what I prefer
# use git mergetool to resolve conflicts, if any
```

At this point, Dev B will have the changes of A and their own in separate branches, where all work is saved and protected. You know from the get-go that merging them will cause conflicts, but now Git will help you deal with that:

```
git checkout dev.protecting-my-work
git rebase `branch` # see possibly lots of conflicts
loop until rebase is complete:
   git mergetool # resolve conflicts manually
   git rebase --continue
```

Then Dev B can finish their work on the private branch, clean up the history using `git rebase -i`, merge with `branch` and push when it's all done and clean.

**A note about rebasing**

You'll notice I recommend rebasing in several cases above, but they all have one thing in common: they all involve rebasing local commits that have never been pushed. That's what I consider safe rebasing. Don't rebase anything you've pushed before.

**PS**

Git can help you get out of this bind, but I would say a refactoring such as Dev A is doing should ideally involve asking colleagues to hold off on other changes to the same repo. Everyone else working in parallel is working on "dirty" code, and no matter what you do, that's going to cause conflicts.